# How to use http-proxy

Tags: node.js, redirect, layout, proxy, http-proxy

I use node.js with express and I have the module http-proxy. I create my proxy like this:

```
var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options);  
proxyServer.listen(8000);
```

and my options are like this:

```
var options = {  
  pathnameOnly: true,
  router: {  
    '/projectone': '127.0.0.1:8001',  
    '/projecttwo: '127.0.0.1:8002'  
}
```

My first question is how I can make a page where there are two 
links and I click on it and the proxy redirect to the right site.. 
For example there's a site with a link "project one" and project two" 
and with a html code like this:

```
 "<a href="http://localhost:8000/projectone">project one</a>"
```

and the proxy will redirect me.. Can I somehow make a site who listen on 8000? How? the code I posted is in the same app.js file like the rest of the program .. after the proxy code I continued like this:

```
//Create http - server listen on 8001 
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Or must I do a third site with the two links?
My second question is that when my url is like "localhost:8000/projectone"
 I get to the right site but my css files and a picture are not loading how can I fix this? Where is the problem? Also this site is a login page. normaly when I'm logged in I get redirect to another page but when I try to login on this site with the right logindata I get redirect to a blank page.. what's the problem here?